# Ruby-On-Rails: Spree - Customer to add order notes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using Spree on Rails. My customers would like to add additional notes to their orders when finalizing their shopping carts. For example, they might want to add an internal reference number.

Is there a way to add an additional optional field that customers can enter, either associated with the entire order or with a line item within that order, that will appear in the order display and invoice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add database column to spree_orders with new migration

```
rake db:create migration AddIRNToSpreeOrders
```

and in created migration file

```
def change
  add_column :spree_orders, :irn, :string
end
```

Add validation if needed in  app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  validates_length_of :irn, minimum: 2, maximum: 254, allow_blank: true
end
```

Permit your new field in controller's strong params  app/controllers/spree/orders_controller_decorator.rb

```
Spree::OrdersController.class_eval do

  private

  def order_params
    if params[:order]
      params[:order].permit(*permitted_order_attributes, :irn)
    end
  end
end
```

Add your new field in orders views by copy and override view file or by defacing https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html